# What is the use of undiscounted Futures/Option Prices

Tags: options, option-pricing, volatility, futures, discounting

Reading the great book of Gatheral on Vol Surfaces ([link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471792519)) I can't help but notice that throughout he uses **undiscounted** option prices (though he obviously never assumed rates to be zero).

See e.g. page 8 where he reviews Dupire's work and derives the pseudo-probability density of the final spot price $S_T$ as
$$\phi(K, T; S_0) = \frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial K^2}$$
with $C$ denoting **undiscounted** option prices. On the other hand, using *discounted* option prices, and letting $D$ be the discount factor at time $T$, one would obtain
$$\phi(K, T; S_0) = \frac{1}{D}\cdot\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial K^2}$$

Similarly, a Bloomberg reference document states Put-Call Parity (together with subsequent derivations) as 
$$C-P=F-K$$
with $C,P$ being the ***future*** values of European call & put options, and $F$ the forward, as opposed to the standard form ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Put%E2%80%93call_parity#Statement)) which reads 
$$C-P = D\cdot(F- K)$$

---

What is the use (or benefit) of doing these derivations with **undiscounted** prices? Does the market quote prices that way?

Comment: It is just to simplify notations

Comment: I see. Wouldn't it be quite fiddly/annoying to retrospectively derive everything again with $D$ inserted in all the right places?

Comment: it would not improve the exposition of ideas imo since the focus here is really about volatilty.

Comment: It's undiscounted as it's about probability, not *discounted* probability